# IBM WebSphere 7 JNDI Configuration - java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: sql-server-2008, websphere-7

[image]

Trying to create JNDI connection with MS SQL Server 2008 in IBM Websphere 7 using "sqljdbc4.jar" but I'm getting this following java.lang.NullPointerException error when I click on finish.

DSRA3601E:createDatasource command failed for the following reason: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: This looks like a product issue (a NullPointerException should never occur).  I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Yea maybe! I have raised a PMR, waiting for a reply!