# Install Worklight server 6.1 fails

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Windows 7 64 bit
Worklight 6.1 server installation image (IM Repository)
Attempted with 2 different versions of IM  1.5.2, and  1.7
WAS 8.0 (Already Installed)
Selected derby database option  (No production env)

See full log here: http://pastebin.com/7GeYvL5e

Comment: Are you running Installation Manager as Admin?

Comment: Previously we've never had to force "run as admin" to install other IM based packages.  Just to be sure we ran as admin, and encountered the same failure.  Appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Could you also paste the content of this file:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AdminAgent01\logs\ffdc\ffdc.2491159109192296653.txt

Also, are you able to issue 'wsadmin' commands on this machine?

Comment: The exception happens in the deployment manager (not the wsadmin client). A web search reveals only these similar reports: 1)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930061/ibm-websphere-7-jndi-configuration-java-lang-nullpointerexception-error
  and 2) https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013935289

Is the used deployment manager of a supported WAS version (7.0.0.29 or newer, 8.0.0.6 or newer, 8.5.0.2 or newer, or 8.5.5)?

Comment: @MichaelMirt, please see above comment.

Comment: We've updated the WAS installationto 8.0.0.8 and attempted to install WL server again. We experirnce the same falure described earlier. Do you feel that installing a later version of WAS (8.5.5) would be of value?

Comment: Yes. Please use a supported version. Try 8.5.5

Comment: Apologize for the late update.  We were successful in installing WL6.1 server with app-store using Liberty 8.5 as the hosting application server.  It appears our issue was in trying to use an existing WAS 8.0 installation.

Comment: @MichaelMirt, please provide the above as an answer so this question could be 'resolved',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were successful in installing WL6.1 server with app-store using Liberty 8.5 as the hosting application server. It appears our issue was in trying to use an existing WAS 8.0 installation